# It is safe to swap drives with different operating systems in a single drive slot?

Tags: linux, windows, boot

I want to install Windows on a newly bought SSD and depending on my needs I would swap it (i.e. replacing the entire drive) with the existing one which currently has an Ubuntu installation on it. My laptop has one internal drive slot and for various reasons I do not want to deal with dual boot. Note that swapping the drives wouldn't happen too often. I would use Windows maybe 2 days a month and Linux the for the rest.

Are there any risks involved when done properly? In the past I've ran into issues which led to recoveries, because the UEFI for some reason did not recognize the old drive anymore when I swapped the previous drive back in.

To clarify: both OSes are installed on the same device, so the drivers and hardware would not conflict.

Comment: What you describe is done all the time.

Comment: Always a risk of physically dropping or shocking (static) or breaking the hard drives, but that wouldn't be doing it properly. If space isn't an issue then dual boot would probably be a lot easier, could always read your windows files from linux too without juggling hard drives.

Comment: The drive has an encrypted LVM (sdb5_crypt). Afaik the partitions shouldn't interfere, but I am not sure about it and therefore don't want to risk it. This is a good followup question I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this in the past.  There should be no reason why the UEFI BIOS should care at all about what you're doing here, just make sure that you shut each system down properly before swapping the drive out.

Comment: This answer is correct. Basically, the UEFI cannot even detect that you have swapped out the disks but it doesn't remember them. (It is saved on a ROM, remember?)